# cake Php :how can we extends AppController?

Tags: php, cakephp

[image]I am developing login functionality in **cakephp**.

I Created **UsersController**,in that login function is there and AppController.phpalso is there in **app/controller/AppController.php**.

I called auth component in **AppController.php**. But thats not working ..

**It's showing AppController not found error ...**

how can we extend Appcontroller page in UsersController?

Please clarify this doubt to me
any one can help..

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Does AppController.php exist? It should exist in the same folder as your UsersController.php

Comment: class AppController extends Controller
 { 
 public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
      'authorize' => 'controller'
    ),
    'Session'
    );
    public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
    }
}

Comment: Are you sure `app/controller/AppController.php` is the path of your `appController` ? if so please change it to `app/Controller/AppController.php`

Comment: Protip: work on your coding standards. It is a big mess!

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the below at the top of your `UsersController` class. This will include the `AppController` class. It is after this you can now extend the AppController or even make reference to it.

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this line ? @ yomexzo

Comment: @user3085661 Declares a package for a class. This package location will be used by the automatic class loader if the class is tried to be used. 
Check: http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-App.html#_uses